# Range of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x):\mathbb{R}^1\to\mathbb{R}^1$ and is continuous. Can this function have the following property? $f(0+)=f(0)=f(0-)=+\infty$

I intuitively understand this but can't expalin this strictly.
Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Every function $f:R^1\to R^1$, continuous or not, must have a real value at $x=0$. As $+\infty$ is not a real number, you will have to rephrase your question.

Comment: @uniquesolution, So my question is nonsense. Right?

Comment: It would make sense if the function had a range in the extended real numbers, but since its range is only the  reals, it has to take a real value at 0.